# Wrong TextView color after ListView filter

Tags: android, listview, textview

I'm searching internet and i don't handle with my problem.

I have ListView with five TextView. One of TextView is colored in some situations. Everything is work ok unless my ListView is not filtered. AFTER FILTERING listview, color changes (switch in getView) in textview `mojView_holder.tekst_wart` not working and stay default.

Maybe some could help me to find solution, please...

This is fragments of my adapter code:

```
public class wiersz_listy_zamowien extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

ArrayList<Zamowienie> zamowienia;
CustomFilter filter;
ArrayList<Zamowienie> filterList;

private Context ctx;

public wiersz_listy_zamowien(Context ctx, ArrayList<Zamowienie> zamowienia) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.zamowienia = zamowienia;
    this.filterList = zamowienia;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return zamowienia.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return zamowienia.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return zamowienia.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

private class ViewHolderPattern {
    TextView tekst_nr;
    TextView tekst_naz;
    TextView tekst_wart;
    TextView tekst_data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolderPattern mojView_holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        mojView_holder = new ViewHolderPattern();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wiersz_listy_zamowien, parent, false);

        mojView_holder.tekst_nr = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nr_zam);
        mojView_holder.tekst_naz = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_zam);
        mojView_holder.tekst_wart = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wart_zam);
        mojView_holder.tekst_data = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.data_zloz_zam);

        convertView.setTag(mojView_holder);
    } else {
        mojView_holder = (ViewHolderPattern) convertView.getTag();
    }

    //Ustawienie danych
    mojView_holder.tekst_nr.setText(zamowienia.get(position).getId());

   mojView_holder.tekst_naz.setText(zamowienia.get(position).getNazwa());

    mojView_holder.tekst_data.setText(zamowienia.get(position).getData());


    mojView_holder.tekst_wart.setText(String.format("%.2f", Float.parseFloat( zamowienia.get(position).getPlatn() )) + " zł ");


    //kolory kwoty zależne od statusu płatności
    switch(zamowienia.get(position).getStatusPlatn()) {
        case "0": mojView_holder.tekst_wart.setTextColor(convertView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.zamZgloszColor)); break;
        default: mojView_holder.tekst_wart.setTextColor(0xFF000000); //silver
    }

    return convertView;
}


@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(filter == null)
    {
        filter=new CustomFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}



//INNER CLASS
class CustomFilter extends Filter
{
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();
        if(constraint != null && constraint.length()>0)
        {
            //CONSTARINT TO UPPER
            constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
            ArrayList<Zamowienie> filters=new ArrayList<Zamowienie>();
            //get specific items
            for(int i=0;i<filterList.size();i++)
            {
                if(filterList.get(i).getNazwa().toUpperCase().contains(constraint))
                {
                    Zamowienie p=new Zamowienie(filterList.get(i).getId(), filterList.get(i).getNazwa(), filterList.get(i).getPlatn(), filterList.get(i).getStatus(), filterList.get(i).getStatusPlatn(), filterList.get(i).getData());
                    filters.add(p);
                }
            }
            results.count=filters.size();
            results.values=filters;
        }else
        {
            results.count=filterList.size();
            results.values=filterList;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        zamowienia=(ArrayList<Zamowienie>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: seriously `Zamowienie p=new Zamowienie(...);filters.add(p)` ? why not `filters.add(filterList.get(i))` ? ... Did you debug the code? ... I bet that for some reasons(fx you fu** up the constructor paramters in Zamowienia all of them seem to be a strings - so it's easy) `!zamowienia.get(position).getStatusPlatn().equals("0")` , always ...

Comment: why so many people extend `BaseAdapter` again and again, instead of using some already existing adapters (avoiding basic errors in custom implementation)?

Answer (score 1):

you can take reference from this code,because after filter your listview item id is getting changed.so implement the getItemId method.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by windev on 8/2/2016.
 */

public class MainAdapter extends   RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;
public ArrayList<DataModel> orig;
Context context;
//String url="http://focusmedica.com/FMAPPS/appcatalogue/";
String url="http://192.168.1.44:81/DOMAINS/Focusmedica.com/FMAPPS/appcatalogue/";

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvChapterName;
    ImageView ivChapterIcon;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.tvChapterName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvChapterName);
        this.ivChapterIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivChapterIcon);
    }
}

public MainAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<DataModel> data) {
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.myOnClickListener);
    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    int itemID;
    // orig will be null only if we haven't filtered yet:
    if (orig == null) {
        itemID = position;
    } else {
        itemID = orig.indexOf(dataSet.get(position));
    }
    return itemID;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

    TextView tvChapterName = holder.tvChapterName;
    ImageView ivChapterIcon = holder.ivChapterIcon;

    String chapterName=dataSet.get(listPosition).getChapterName();
    String iconName = chapterName.replaceAll(" ", "_");
    tvChapterName.setText(chapterName);
    Picasso.with(context).load(url+iconName+".png").into(ivChapterIcon);
    //ivChapterIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.caticon);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}

public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final ArrayList<DataModel> results = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
            if (orig == null)
                orig = dataSet;
            if (constraint != null) {
                if (orig != null && orig.size() > 0) {
                    for (final DataModel g : orig) {
                        if (g.getChapterName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())||
                                g.getChapterName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            dataSet = (ArrayList<DataModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
  }
}
```